# What is the rank of the Baer-Specker group $\prod\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Most of the question is said in the title: Is it known what the rank of $\prod\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$ i.e. the dimension of  $\mathbb{Q}\otimes\prod\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector-space is? Surely it is infinite but it is uncountable and if so, does one know uncountable of which cardinality?

I know that $\hom_\mathbb{Z}(\prod\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\cong\bigoplus\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$, is this already enough to conclude that the rank is countable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A=\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ is torsion-free, the canonical map $A\to \mathbb{Q}\otimes A$ is injective.  It follows that $\mathbb{Q}\otimes A$ has the same cardinality as $A$, and since this cardinality is uncountable the dimension is the same as the cardinality, namely $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Answer (score 5):

The rank of the Baer-Specker group equals the cardinality of the continuum.  In fact, a theorem of Nöbeling says that the subgroup consisting of the bounded sequences is free. Since that subgroup has the cardinality of the continuum, its rank is also the cardinality of the continuum.